# Help parse "the sanctions come as travel bans and asset freezes... failed to ..."

Tags: parsing

> **The sanctions come as travel bans and asset freezes aimed at President Vladimir Putin’s inner circle failed to force the country to meet an ultimatum to end support for separatists** in two mainly Russian-speaking regions in eastern Ukraine.
>
> Russia and Ukraine blamed each other for the downing of a Malaysia
> Airlines jet yesterday that killed all 298 people on board in an
> incident that may prove to be a turning point in the five-month
> conflict between their countries. The U.S. said this week that Russia
> is supplying the rebels with weapons.
>
> -- [Source](http://www.garp.org/risk-news-and-resources/risk-headlines/story.aspx?newsId=114699)

I find the bold sentence ungrammatical. **The sanctions** seems to act as the subject for both **come** and **failed** here.

The only way for the sentence to be grammatical could be to regard **asset freezes** as the subject for **failed**, but obviously it won't work semantically. The sanctions include travel bans and asset freezes.

I would think it should be "the sanctions **coming** as travel bans and asset freezes aimed at President Vladimir Putin’s inner circle failed to force the country to..."

Please help me parse it.

Comment: The whole sentence can be reduced to "The sanctions come". The subject of *failed* is *bans and freezes*.

Comment: Suppose the sanctions had no economic qualities, would the sentence be contextually regarded as wrong? @DamkerngT.

Comment: In my opinion, that sentence, though a bit lengthy, reads fine. To me sanction is some sort of an action, so the sentence will still read fine for me even when we replace that sanctions with *a meeting*, *an announcement*, *a decision*, and so on.

Comment: I'm good, but apparently you are better than me. Thx! @DamkerngT. This week I met with a CEO from your country. :-)

Comment: Have a nice and successful meeting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **main clause** of the sentence is

> The sanctions come.

Everything else in this sentence is a single long **subordinate *as* clause** expressing the occasion for the ‘coming’ of the sanctions—when and why they came.

The **subject** of this subordinate clause is

> Travel bans and asset freezes aimed at President Vladimir Putin’s inner circle ...

- The last part of that, *aimed at President Vladimir Putin's inner circle*, is a participle phrase modifying *Travel bans and asset freezes*. You may understand it as ***which were aimed*** at ..., and indeed many linguists would parse it as a relative clause ‘reduced’ by ‘Whiz-deletion’—deleting the [*Wh-* word + *BE* form].

These bans and freezes are, as you say, sanctions. However, they are not the sanctions which are the subject of the main clause—those are **new** sanctions, severe constraints on lending to Russian financial institutions and energy companies. The sanctions in the subordinate clause are earlier sanctions, whose result is expressed in the **predicate** of the subordinate clause:

> ... failed to force the country to meet an ultimatum to end support for separatists in two mainly Russian-speaking regions in eastern Ukraine.

In summary:

> The (new) sanctions come as earlier sanctions failed to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Yes, that's an attributive participle phrase. I remember my high school exams were stuffed full of questions on that. Teachers in China are always obssessed with those tricky usages, which I think go far beyond good learning. That's why I have been asking lots of searching questions. :-)

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I think I have to disagree with "far beyond good learning", at least if you are teaching students who will be called on to read a lot of formal prose. Participle phrases like this are very common there.

Comment: Sorry, I really miswrote that. It should've been 'against'. I had intended to mean that was not a good way of learning English. I'm not a teacher(see my info), but I was made into a cookie-cutter mold by my teachers in China. Thus, I feel compelled to ask searching questions than are necessary. That's it. @StoneyB

Comment: And yes, participle phrases like this are common in all kinds of articles. What I meant was that teachers in China sometimes did seem to lay too much more stress on some tricky usages than are necessary. That's why even some native speakers couldn't pass the exams created by them. Now, English-learning is no longer a compulsory course in China. It's really a big reform. @Stoney

Comment: Well, whatever you don't teach is what your students will run into! ... Searching questions are the reason I'm here--they're driving me deeper into the grammar than I ever expected to have to go, but it's fun.

Comment: I feel fun too. And I don't think lots of people are fond of it. Even some of professors in my university couldn't go that deep even though they do have a really impressive command of English. But they have their own talent like arts, speeches, etc. @Stoney

Answer (score 3):

- The sanctions come into force (now)

Why do they come into force? On what backdrop? In what kind of situation?

- They come into force because earlier measures failed to force Russia to end support for separatists

What kind of measures?

- **Travel bans and asset freezes** aimed at President Vladimir Putin’s inner circle

**Travel bans and assets freezes** were the first wave of sanctions. The article speaks about the second wave of sanctions, striking against not individuals but whole companies.

Here, the word **as** is used in the sense of **while**, so the words

> The sanctions come as travel bans and asset freezes

do not mean

> The sanctions comprise travel bans and asset freezes

Comment: I see, but I still feel it's kind of bad-writing. I wonder if a native speaker would misunderstand that like I did.

Comment: I guess this is 'journalist style' writing, with sentences over-burdened with meaning. I think a native speaker is prepared to parse such condensed, compressed sentenses.

Comment: As a native speaker I do have to say that I had to read that sentence twice to fully parse it.

Comment: That's reassuring. :-) @JasonC